# Isset still not doing its job

Tags: php, isset

I've seen this issue all over stack overflow but none of the methods helped.

Form:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
      <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="User Name">
      <input name="rawpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <input value="Login" type="submit">
</form>
```

Login.php:

```
// Gets user entered details from form.
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $username=$_POST['username'];
} else {
  $username=null;
}
if (isset($_POST['rawpassword'])) {
  $rawpassword=$_POST['rawpassword'];
} else {
  $rawpassword=null;
}

// Hashes password through SHA-1.
$password = sha1($rawpassword);

echo "$username";
echo "$rawpassword";
echo "$password";
```

My problem is that the

```
if (isset($_POST['']))
```

is coming back as false and will make both variables null and echos null (nothing). But if I was to do this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['']))
```

It returns the undefined index error that everyone gets.

Help will be much appricated.

Comment: Why would you possibly run `isset($_POST[''])`?

Comment: How are both values posted? Can you provide the form HTML code, or Ajax call, or whatever else you use to let the user submit the data?

Comment: I think he's using that as a sort of wildcard that represents either of $_POST['username'] and $_POST['rawpassword'] ...

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST);` output?

Comment: I mean `isset($_POST['username'])` & `isset($_POST['rawpassword'])` without having to actually copy then both out on the question. Im not actaully running `isset($_POST['']` Im just trying to get the question as compact as I can.

Comment: @Nunchy Yep, thats what I was trying to do.

Comment: @trincot this is echoed: `Array()`

Comment: Then nothing has been POSTed. Please provide your form.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong between form and PHP. Can you see if there is a redirect happening in the middle (check your browser developer tools).

Comment: Have you tried $_REQUEST instead of $_POST

Comment: As @Anant mentioned this is likely due to filename discrepancy or another simple syntax error in some part that you haven't posted here.  As it stands this should work fine.  Voting to close.

Comment: @Anant i've fixed the file name issue which I didn't notice at first, but i'm still having the same issue.

Comment: I think it's unlikely a filename issue, unless it is causing a specific redirect to the right file since OP managed to dump out $_POST. If a redirect is happening, POST data will probably be getting dropped.

Comment: The problem is that his code works fine on a test server as it's posted.  So presumably the actual code on his server is different than what's here in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue that I was having, obviously I didn't do enough research to find out that the problem was that JQuerymobile (should have mentioned that I was using JQuerymobile) has it's own special ways of requesting pages.

All I needed to do was add `data-ajax="false"` into the `<form>` tag, now everything works how I wanted it to work.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username=$_POST['username'];
}
```

Please try checking submit too as username and other field are not always set.
I'm expecting this to be the problem as The quesion is unclear without html.

Answer (score 0):

try using this in

---

HTML

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
  <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="User Name" required>
  <input name="rawpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
  <input value="Login" type="submit" name="Login">
</form>
```

---

PHP

```
<?php
if (filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Login')==='Login') {
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $rawpassword=$_POST['rawpassword'];
  // Hashes password through SHA-1.
  $password = sha1($rawpassword);
} else {
    $username='';
    $rawpassword='';
}


echo $username;
echo $rawpassword;
echo $password;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [empty()](http://php.net/empty) instead of [isset()](http://php.net/isset). Because `isset()` will only check if the (POST) variable is set and not NULL. It will not check if it's empty or not. If someone just clicks on submit without entering any username or password, your code will still accept this. If you use `empty()` instead, it will also check if both username and password aren't empty. Since `empty()` does the exact same as `isset()`, but also checks if it's not empty, it's no longer needed to use `isset()`.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['username'] && !empty($_POST['rawpassword'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $rawpassword = $_POST['rawpassword'];

    // Hashes password through SHA-1.
    $password = sha1($rawpassword);
} else {
    $username = null;
    $rawpassword = null;
}

echo $username;
echo $rawpassword;
echo $password;

?>
```

Also, it's not nessesary to put variables inside quotes when echoing them out.

Comment: I've tried your method but still no success. I don't think this could cause the issue but I'm currently running the latest version of Wampserver64 and the url is localhost as ive not port forwarded. Would it be worth it to check on a shared hosting site to see if this code works on a server?

Comment: @DTYlan Hmm you can try, but it should not matter. As long as you use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in your browser to visit your website, there's no need to port forward anything. It should still work perfectly fine for you.

Comment: @DTYlan Are you filling in the form before checking this code? Because if you simply only load this code and skip your form, then it will always return null. `$_POST['']` variables are always null if you don't post anything with the form first.

Comment: Yep, I'm filling in the form.

Comment: @DTYlan Hmm well this code is fine, so that can't be the problem. I'm afraid there's not much else I can do without seeing it for myself. But the only way to do that would be though Teamviewer. Unfortunetely I'm still working though. It'll be 2 more hours before I can help you out with that. So you'll need some patience if you want me to do that.

Comment: I believe it must be a problem with `$_POST` because I switched the form and login.php to `method="get"` & `$_GET` and it works. But why would `$_POST` not work?